# Pegar um vetor dentro de uma matriz em R

Tags: array, r, matriz

Estou fazendo um exercício* para meus estudos em R e não estou conseguindo manipular matrizes devidamente. O problema é muito simples, aparentemente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho uma matriz 'm'

`m <- rbind( c(1,1), c(1,2), c(3,3), c(2,0))`,

e simplesmente gostaria de pegar o valor em cada uma das posições. Nesse caso, queria armazenar o vetor `(1,1)` em uma variável, depois o `(1,2)` e assim por diante. O objetivo final é usar cada vetor da matriz e realizar o cálculo da distância entre o ponto `x` e esse vetor.

Não consegui fazer de nenhuma forma automatizada percorrendo todas as posições. Alguém pode ajudar?

Código Completo:

```
get_neighbor <- function(x, m, k){
  for(len in 1:dim(m)[len]){
    len <- len
  }
  
  if (k > len){
    return("The k is higher than ...")
  }
  else{
    for(i in 1:len){
      m <- m[1]
      print(m)
    }
    d <- sqrt(sum((x - m)^2))
    cat("The distance is", d, "\n")
  }
}

len <- 1
i <- 1
x <- c(0,2)
m <- rbind( c(1,1), c(1,2), c(3,3), c(2,0))
get_neighbor(x, m, 1)
```

Comment: (Não fui eu que votei para baixo)  1) Em `for(len in 1:dim(m)[len])`, como é que `len`é a variável que indexa `dim(.)` se ainda não está definida; 2) E já agora, quantas dimensões tem `m`? 3) O que é que a instrução `len <- len` faz?

Answer (score 3):

A função abaixo usa só um ciclo `apply`, o resto é vetorizado.

```
get_neighbor <- function(x, m, k){
  # função auxiliar
  dist_xy <- function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))
  
  # verificar se k é válido
  # em primeiro lugar, tem que ser positivo
  if(k < 1){
    warning("k is not positive, returning NULL.")
    return( invisible(NULL) )
  }
  
  # em segundo lugar, não pode ser maior que o
  # número de linhas da matriz 'm'
  if(k > nrow(m)){
    mname <- deparse(substitute(m))
    msg <- sprintf("k is larger than the rows of %s.", mname)
    message(msg)
    return( invisible(NULL) )
  }
  
  # agora determinar o k-ésimo vizinho mais próximo
  # 'd' são as distâncias das linhas da matriz a 'x'
  d <- apply(m, 1, dist_xy, x)
  # qual das distâncias é a k-ésima?
  i <- match(k, order(d))
  # é essa que queremos
  m[i, ]
}


x <- c(0,2)
m <- rbind( c(1,1), c(1,2), c(3,3), c(2,0))

get_neighbor(x, m, 1)
#[1] 1 2
get_neighbor(x, m, 2)
#[1] 1 1
get_neighbor(x, m, 3)
#[1] 2 0
get_neighbor(x, m, 4)
#[1] 3 3

get_neighbor(x, m, 10)
#k is larger than the rows of m.

get_neighbor(x, m, -1)
#Warning message:
#In get_neighbor(x, m, -1) : k is not positive, returning NULL.
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Rui! Entendi perfeitamente o que eu estava errando. Me salvou demais, valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Eu não faria deste jeito, mas corrigindo a sua solução:

```
get_neighbor <- function(x, m, k){
  len <- dim(m)[1]

  if (k > len){
    return("The k is higher than ...")
  }
  else{
    for(i in 1:len){
      m1 <- m[i, ]
      d <- sqrt(sum((x - m1)^2))
      cat("The distance is", d, "\n")
    }
  }
}

x <- c(0,2)
m <- rbind( c(1,1), c(1,2), c(3,3), c(2,0))
k <- 4

get_neighbor(x, m, k)

> The distance is 1.414214 
> The distance is 1 
> The distance is 3.162278 
> The distance is 2.828427
```

Em R, o mais simplificado seria:

```
dist(rbind(x,m))[1:dim(m)[1]]
[1] 1.414214 1.000000 3.162278 2.828427
```

Comment: Como você faria, Daniel? Eu tentei essa abordagem porque parece ser a requisitada pelo professor. De qualquer forma, gostei da sua solução. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!